# TCP Window size is not increasing from 1536 bytes in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, kernel, https, tcp-ip

TCP window size is constant(1536 bytes) while sending TCP request across two machines connected by switch.

Configuration added in sysctl to change TCP parameters are following

```
fs.nr_open = 10000000
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 786432 1697152 1945728
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 4096 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 4096 16777216
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.core.rmem_default = 16777216
net.core.wmem_default = 16777216
```

uname -a

```
6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How to increase the tcp window size